# "Create" not working with ruby paranoia on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-paranoia

I've implemented paranoia on a model ("Stays"), which is working in development, but not in production on heroku. On the heroku site, I can see an (expectedly empty) index page, but when I go to /stays/new, I get an error page.

Checking the logs, I find this:

```
    2017-01-18T03:31:49.546164+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5ce2502-2cb9-4b1d-9888-f2990881bbb4] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
    2017-01-18T03:31:49.547115+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5ce2502-2cb9-4b1d-9888-f2990881bbb4] ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'deleted_at' for Stay.):
    2017-01-18T03:31:49.547194+00:00 app[web.1]: [d5ce2502-2cb9-4b1d-9888-f2990881bbb4] app/controllers/stays_controller.rb:14:in `new'
```

In app/controllers/stays_controller.rb, here are the first 15 lines.

```
    class StaysController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_stay, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

      def index
        @stays = Stay.all.order("created_at DESC")
      end

      def show
      end

      def new
        @stay = current_user.stays.build #Stay.new
      end
```

In the gemfile:

```
gem 'paranoia', '~> 2.2'
```

In app/models/stay.rb:

```
class Stay < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_paranoid
end
```

I've run `heroku run rake db:migrate` since pushing to heroku, but with no luck. Any idea why this is working locally for development, but not on heroku for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post migration, you need to do a heroku restart since the application is running in production mode. Heroku caches the db schema before any migrations are run. Thus, restarting the application will recache the schema.

Just run and your problem should not persist.

```
heroku restart
```

Comment: Just noting, that had the same issue on a Digial Ocean machine, too